# Exporting large file in node with database lookup - Avoid multiple DB calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, caching

I'm fairly new to Node and although I think it is great for service type apps I'm having some issues when using it for apps that simply run from end to end like a data export app when callbacks are needed for accessing databases or other such things.

Here is my current setup.

I have a script that exports data from MongoDB into an XML file to be used in a separate process. The export script is simple enough:

```
db.getData(function(err, data) {
    data.forEach(function(entry) {
        // write the data to the file
        writeData(entry);
    });
});
```

The problem is when I need to make a non-synchronous call during the export such as:

```
db.getData(function(err, data) {
    data.forEach(function(entry) {

        var cacheValue = cache.get(entry.someOtherId);

        if (cacheValue) {
            // write the value from the cache
            writeData(entry, cacheValue);
        }

        else {

            // THIS IS CALLED 1000's OF TIMES EVEN THOUGH THE FIRST FEW CALLS
            // SHOULD POPULATE THE CACHE

            db.getLookup(entry.someOtherId, function(err, value) {

                // store it in the cache to avoid db calls
                cache.store(entry.someOtherId, value);

                // write the data to the file after getting the lookup
                writeData(entry, value);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Due to the non-blocking nature of node while `getLookup` is being performed the main `forEach` loop will continue, and because the `entry.someOtherId` field is a lookup, often it will contain the same value as another record.

So what happens is that for a large file with a relatively small amount of lookups I get thousands of database calls sent into `getLookup` before the first one has a chance to return and store the value in the cache.

**Pre-Loading not desired**

I know I could simply re-load the cache as the lookup table is fairly small, but how should this be tackled for larger lookups where it is not practical to re-cache all the values?

**Pausing the main loop**

In a synchronous environment this would be simple, the main loop would stop until the DB value is returned so next time round the value is already in the cache.

I know there are various libraries that try to stop thread execution until a callback returns but that seems to go against what Node is.

**Can someone tell me what is the generally accepted pattern for handling this type of situation in Node?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a promise library and a memoization function to solve the task of handling multiple asynchronous operations that run in parallel.

For the following example I'm using bluebird. Your entire loop, including result caching, can be reduced to this rather clearly arranged piece of code:

```
var db = Promise.promisifyAll(db);
var lookup = memoize(db.getLookupAsync, db);

entries.forEach(function (entry) {
    lookup(entry.someOtherId).then(function (value) {
        writeData(entry, value);
    });
});
```

where `memoize` is a generic helper function that caches function results:

```
function memoize(func, thisArg) {
    var cache = {};
    return function memoize(id) {
        if (!cache.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            cache[id] = func.apply(thisArg || this, arguments);
        }
        return cache[id];
    };
}
```

So `lookup()` is a function that calls the *promisified* version of `db.getLookup()` (bluebird's `.promisifyAll()` creates `...Async()` versions of all the functions in an object) and memoizes the respective result.

A promisified function returns a promise that resolves (i.e. calls its `.then()` callback) as soon as data is available, or immediately (if it already has resolved before). In other words, we can cache a promise and call `.then()` on it as often as we want.

With this setup we have all we need to solve your task of handling asynchronous function calls while caching their results to keep the process as fast as possible. Plus it is pleasant, straight-forward to read, as opposed to "callback hell".

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/91bdb5ns/, where you can see it work.

Note that there is no error handling in my code. You should read into [the bluebird docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) and add it yourself.

Comment: this is great! Exactly the type of approach I was looking for

Comment: Thanks. BTW, libraries like underscore or lodash have memoization functions. If you are already using one of those, you should switch from my implementation to a properly tested one.

Answer (score 1):

I think I now truly understand the expression `callback hell`

It turns out (rather unsurprisingly really) that this needs to all be done in callbacks and recursive functions, so the next entry is not started until the previous entry has finished:

Using the method described here:
[Using recursive pattern loop with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161894/using-recursive-pattern-loop-with-node-js/13820469)

Processing an array of values, the array is passed into a function along with an index, when the value for that index has been processed it calls itself with an index of index+1:

```
function processEntry(entries, index, next) {

    // no more entries to run
    if (index >= entries.length) {
        next();
        return;
    }

    var cacheValue = cache.get(entry.someOtherId);

    if (cacheValue) {

        // write the value from the cache
        writeData(entry, cacheValue);

        // process the next entry
        process.nextTick(function() {
            processEntry(entries, index+1, next);
        });
    }

    else {

        db.getLookup(entry.someOtherId, function(err, value) {

            // store it in the cache to avoid db calls
            cache.store(entry.someOtherId, value);

            // write the data to the file after getting the lookup
            writeData(entry, value);

            // process the next entry
            processEntry(entries, index+1, next);
        });
    }

}
```

**Avoiding a Stack Overflow**

The problem with this setup is that once the cache has been populated we would start calling `processEntry` from directly within `processEntry` and not from a different callback's stack so before long we would get a stack overflow.

To avoid this we need to tell Node to create a new stack by using `process.nextTick()`
http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback

> On the next loop around the event loop call this callback. This is not a simple alias to setTimeout(fn, 0), it's much more efficient. It typically runs before any other I/O events fire, but there are some exceptions. See process.maxTickDepth below.

According to the documentation this call is fairly efficient