# How can I pass an incrementing for-loop variable to a function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass values to a callback function at the time of the request call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892455/how-to-pass-values-to-a-callback-function-at-the-time-of-the-request-call)

I know this is a general problem and not only in node.js. I have to pass a variable from the for loop to a function which I want to generate. The functions are stored in an array and have to remember these variables.

Here is my example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < administratorIds.length; i ++){
  adminCallbacks[adminCallbacks.length] = function(callback){
    model_user.getById(administratorIds[i], function(user){
      administrators[administrators.length] = {name: user.getName()};
      callback(null, null);
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new variable scope for each iteration of the loop.

Only way to do that will be by invoking a function.

```
for(var i = 0; i < administratorIds.length; i++){
  adminCallbacks[adminCallbacks.length] = createHandler(i); // pass i
}

 // receive i as j-----v
function createHandler(j) {
     // return a function...
    return function(callback){
          // ...that uses j-----------------v
        model_user.getById(administratorIds[j], function(user){
          administrators[administrators.length] = {name: user.getName()};
          callback(null, null);
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) perhaps?

```
for(var i = 0; i < administratorIds.length; i ++){
    adminCallbacks.push(
        (function(i){
            return function(callback){
                model_user.getById(
                    administratorIds[i],
                    function(user){
                        administrators[administrators.length] = {name: user.getName()};
                        callback(null, null);
                    }
                );
            };
        })(i)
    );
}
```

Yikes... look at that madness. Anyway, this part:

```
(function(i){
    // stuff!
})(i);
```

captures the current value for i in a closure and thus ensures that it doesn't change once the callback is fired.

An example:

```
var i = 10;
var lockedI = (function(i){
    return function(){ console.log('i is --> ' + i); };
})(i);
var unlockedI = function(){ console.log('i is --> ' + i); };

lockedI();
// i is --> 10

unlockedI();
// i is --> 10

var i = 666;

lockedI();
// i is --> 10;

unlockedI();
// i is --> 666
```

Victory?

Comment: bah... or, what "am not i am" said... :p